# why isn't this working? (spawning a chest with BlockEntityTag)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've made a chest that gives you random items. It works, but now I want that is spawns a chest wit random items.

This works:

```
/give @p minecraft:chest 1 0 {BlockEntityTag:{LootTable:"mctools:chests/loot_table"}}
```

And this does not:

```
/setblock ~1 ~ ~ chest 1 0 {BlockEntityTag:{LootTable:"mctools:chests/loot_table"}}
```

What's wrong? Or it is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

The `BlockEntityTag` compound is for items, holding data to apply to the tile entity corresponding to the item.

Simply remove that tag:

```
/setblock ~1 ~ ~ chest 1 0 {LootTable:"mctools:chests/loot_table"}
```